# Solr schema-browser hyphen escaped problem

Tags: solr

Hello there i'm trying to get the list of the imported field Movie_name

How ever the hyphen was escaped and not showing like this img example
[image]

And this the data i attached already

[image]

```
Like you see two data with the Movie_name
        "Movie_name":"sci-Fi2"},
        "Movie_name":"sci-Fi"}]
```

What i'm trying to do is a simple analytics & get all the list of names with the field Movie_name and not the data.
**So the question why the hyphen are escaped in the schema-browser**
Why i cannot get the exactly correct field name ???

Answer (score 2):

It's not being escaped - what you're seeing in the schema browser are the *actual terms* stored in the index (what is usually referred to as "tokens"). If you want these to be preserved in the original form (i.e. as a single token) to be used for faceting or analytics, store them as the type `string` instead of as a text based field (which have a tokenizer attached - and that tokenizer usually splits the string into multiple smaller tokens on natural split points, such as `-`).

In your example, `sci-fi` is turned into `sci` and `fi`. If you use a `string` type, or a `KeywordTokenizer`, the input is kept as it is, and the token is stored as  `sci-fi` instead.

Comment: Thank you MatsLindh i just changed from text_general to type="string" but the problem what happend if the data already stored and i want to change 1 field to string is that possible because i try string type before and that why i fail each time because the data already stored as text_general

Comment: Changing field types will require you to reindex all your content - i.e. submit it to the index again.